# How to get content in component link field on DXA?

Tags: dxa

I'm implementing DXA(STRI, SDL Tridion Reference Implementation).
I cannot get content of component that is linked from a component link field.

My schema is following.

- Schema name is "Link"
- It has a component link field named "linkToComponent"
- Now "LinkToComponent" links to a component based on "GeneralHeading"
  schema.

When I defined a string property corresponds with the component link field in model class,
the property returns URL. (The URL is a page the linked compoent is used.)

```
namespace Sdl.Web.Site.Areas.Test.Models
{
    public class Link:EntityBase
    {
        [SemanticProperty(PropertyName = "linkToComponent")]
        public string LinkToComponent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I defined a property which type is model class corresponds with "GeneralHeading" schema,
it casuse an error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

```
namespace Sdl.Web.Site.Areas.Clarion.Models
{
    public class Link:EntityBase
    {
        [SemanticProperty(PropertyName = "linkToComponent")]
        public GeneralHeading LinkToComponent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I preview the page on CME, generated XML contains content in linked component.So I belive it's possible to get it in DXA.

How can I get content in component linked in component link field?

Comment: can you put the full error (message and stacktrace) you get ?

Comment: I could get linked component by adding GetCompLinks and GetCompLink method to DD4TModelBuilder following stackexchange. Also, I realize customizing DXA itself is possible by downloading source code from GitHub.